# Is There A Software Way to "Wake" a "Sleeping" Touchscreen on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

Here's my issue. It may be device-specific, but I won't know for a bit. I haven't heard about it from my beta-testers, but I don't actually hear much from them anyway. There's a good chance they wouldn't report it, as it's such a minor "niggle."

I have an iPhone SE as my LET (Low-End Target). I have an app that keeps it awake for hours (a clock that runs while powered).

After a number of hours, the app triggers an alarm.

You dismiss the alarm by touching the screen. The alarm makes a transparent UIView with a touch gesture recognizer attached, visible.

I have found that, after several hours, you need to touch the screen TWICE. I suspect that it's because the OS puts the touch sensor into some kind of "sleep" mode, after a long time with no input.

I can't get this to happen without waiting for many hours.

I haven't seen this documented anywhere, so I'm wondering if there's some kind of UIDevice call that I can make to "prod" the touchscreen awake when the alarm sounds, so the first touch works.

Any ideas.

Comment: Maybe call this app become active in appDelegate UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should toggle that when the alarm sounds. That might be something to try.

Comment: @Tushar  Katyal It looks like toggling the timerDisabled state may do it. I want to give it another day or so of testing, but it worked first time (for the first time) today.

Comment: @Tushar Katyal It looks like toggling the idle timer is the answer! If you post your comment as an answer, I’ll greencheck you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this app become active in appDelegate `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`

Comment: Just to clarify: What I do is TOGGLE isIdleTimerDisabled. It was already set (which is why the app is still up, hours later). I just turn it off, then on again. That seems to wake the touch sensor.